# Why is smtplib.SMTP().sendmail not sending a DKIM signed message

Tags: python, email, smtplib, postfix-mta, dkim

I have set up postfix on a server, along with openDKIM.

When I run:

```
echo "Testing setup" | mail -s "Postfix test" {my_email_address}
```

I get the email, and in the mail headers there is a `DKIM-Signature` header.

When, however I write a python script to send an email, using smtplib:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.utils import make_msgid

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
part1 = MIMEText('Hello, world', 'plain')
msg.attach(part1)
msg['From'] = 'alert@{my_domain}'
msg['To'] = '{my_email_address}'
msg['Subject'] = 'Test Email'
msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid()

mailer = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
mailer.sendmail('alert@{my_domain}', '{my_email_address}', msg.as_string())
mailer.quit()
```

The email that arrives in my inbox is missing the `DKIM-Signature` header, and in the `Authentication-Results` I see `dkim=none (no signatures found);`

So my question is:
Do I need to sign my email manually (eg. with dkimpy), or is there some setting I can enable to have it signed for me?

Let me know if there is any extra information you want/need.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say for sure since you haven't included any configuration or log information. But the OpenDKIM information has this to say:

> A message will be verified unless it conforms to the signing criteria,
>   which are: (1) the domain on the From: address (if present) must be
>   listed by the *−d* command line switch or the *Domain* configuration file
>   setting, and (2) (a) the client connecting to the MTA must have
>   authenticated, or (b) the client connecting to the MTA must be listed
>   in the file referenced by the *InternalHosts* configuration file setting
>   (or be in the default list for that option), or (c) the client must be
>   connected to a daemon port named by the *MTAs* configuration file
>   setting, or (d) the MTA must have set one or more macros matching the
>   criteria set by the *MacroList* configuration file setting.

In your SMTP code, you have clearly not authenticated to the MTA. So then the question becomes, does your configuration allow OpenDKIM to notice your desire in any of the other ways, such as having localhost in InternalHosts? (I think that is the default, but maybe you've overridden it.)