# DKIM fails when sending mails with smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib, dkim

I'm trying to send emails with smtplib and they seem to be delivering fine. The only problem is that DKIM fails and the mails usually go straight to the spam folder.

DKIM is enabled on my shared hosting (host is a2hosting, if that helps) and the process works fine when sending individual emails with Thunderbird, and DKIM passes, suggesting that the problem lies on my end.

I even tried using dkimpy to explicitly sign the emails using the private key but I still get dkim=fail under ARC-Authentication-Results.
Some posts and answers I referred to suggested "logging in" as the solution but I am already logging in using SMTP.login() and as I mentioned earlier, the emails are being sent.

An answer I referred to mentioned that it is the server's job to sign the email and it's worth mentioning that the raw email output includes the DKIM signature, even without explicitly signing it with dkimpy, indicating that the server is signing as expected.

But the problem remains that DKIM fails affecting the email deliverability, and the raw output does not provide any details as to why DKIM failed for the domain.

I use the following code snippet to send an email

```py
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'myemail@mydomain.tld'
    msg['To'] = 'someemail@gmail.com'
    msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
    msg.attach(MIMEText("SomeText", "plain"))

    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("mydomain.tld:465")
    s.login("myemail@mydomain.tld", "mypassword")
    s.sendmail("myemail@mydomain.tld", 'someemail@gmail.com',msg.as_string())
```

I tried signing the message as follows

```py
headers = ["To", "From", "Subject"]
with open("cert.pem") as fh:
    dkim_private = fh.read()
sig = dkim.sign(
            message=msg.as_string().encode("ascii"),    
            selector=str(dkim_selector).encode("ascii"),
            domain="robogyan.tech".encode("ascii"),
            privkey=dkim_private.encode("ascii"),
            include_headers=headers,)
msg["DKIM-Signature"] = sig.decode("ascii").lstrip("DKIM-Signature: ")
```

The raw output did reflect the signature with the above code but DKIM still failed.

There seems to be no problem with the authentication whatsoever since the server replies with "Authentication succeeded"

**Edit:**

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;

    d=mydomain.tld; s=default; h=Subject:To:From:MIME-Version:Content-Type:

    Sender:Reply-To:Date:Message-ID:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:

    Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc

    :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:

    List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;

    bh=giCDGo/0duFr1Ex65l7Ixc3N45EAULK+gw5cHV8pO0k=; b=DR08Q+CjgOLqo8WkLJs/XROfTw

    Z7+ph+qnzi5p49cT3+UwQolcL1CKIVPk7XRkL8WZ3FFa9hZuc6TumquRSiYd5uR0AC5Z3lopEfnQe

    fdbOOTRnks2ZzoOnQusy/gmydUttypu8wTthFhy7vTWXMFcdI29X/HkrokCtiGKCoD2u2kWBtn2sm

    3/aP83lBbMpcWsNbvo3HTsL71o8QPd6bVKpqRGyAy89cAwMLwP4dnJ9WcCxxNzowlJNPQja3o5W16

    t3rG/KizcRehjaDUXhPPRF/4RdYUSIi/SGNwmIPwvkZNc17k3wQpszKeG6/Ujgax/i7Li7V7dLJBT

    Fu/x6xDA==;

Signed-by: myemail@mydomain.tld

Expected-Body-Hash: giCDGo/0duFr1Ex65l7Ixc3N45EAULK+gw5cHV8pO0k=
```

Here's the DKIM of the failing email if that helps. The expected body hash and the received body hash match too. I am not sure what the problem is then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a lot of research and brute force approaches, I finally found the solution to my problem.
I needed to include the Message-ID and the date in the headers as well.
Adding the following lines to the code helped me pass the verification.

```py
msg['Date'] = email.utils.formatdate()
msg['Message-ID'] = email.utils.make_msgid(domain='mydomain.tld')
```

Comment: Many MTAs have (WHM/CPanel/SpamExperts) modules that add missing Message-Id header and thus invalidate the DKIM signature created before that.

Comment: At least In my case setting custom date wasn't needed, only custom Message-ID was needed. But is there a way to auto detect it like `(domain='[autodetect_domain]')`?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was pulling my hairs and investigating the documentation. You just saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Important note: you need to add your smtp client's machine IP address to `InternalHosts` list, because OpenDKIM will check client's permission with [these rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127173/528488).

The you need to add this line to your `/etc/opendkim.conf`:

```
InternalHosts    file:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts   # or any location you want
```

Content of `/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts` could look like:

```
127.0.0.1
::1
localhost
<server_ip>
hostname.example1.com
example1.com
hostname.example2.com
example2.com
...
```

It's just for example. You need to put here your python smtplib-client machine's address (ip/host).

Then just restart your `opendkim`:

```
$ sudo service opendkim restart
```